# jQuery howto : hover a link the div fadeIn, mouseout the link OR the div , the div fadeOut

Tags: jquery, hover, show-hide, mouseenter, mouseleave

ok please consider the following scenario.

I have 2 links , both are in

tags contained in a  tag.

basically, hovering over link A would trigger the animation of a box below which fadeIn, and on mouseout of link A and mouseOut of the box, the box fadeOut.

same with link B, it triggers animation of a different box.

There are some php conditions which happen between the links and the box.

```
<ul class="links">
<li class="linkA"><a><span>Hover here to see BOX A</span></a></li>
<li class="linkB"><a><span>Hover me to see BOX B</span></a></li>
</ul>


<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<div id="boxA">
Some content here for Box A
</div>
<?;}

else { ?>
<div id="boxB" >
Content for Box B
</div>
<?php }
?> 

<style>
ul,
li {list-type:none; display:inline}
li.linkA a {display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background:url(my_image_A.png) no-repeat;}
li .linkB a {display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background:url(my_image_B.png) no-repeat;}

boxA,
boxB {width:300px;height:180px;border:4px solid #00aaff;background:yellow; display: none;}
<script>

jQuery(".linkA").hover(function() {
jQuery("#boxA").fadeIn('fast').css('display', 'block');
 }, function() {
jQuery("#boxA").fadeOut('fast')
});
</script>
```

It just doesn't work properly. The boxes fade out as soon as mouse leave the link. I would like the box to stay visible until the mouse leave the link and/or the box...

Answer (score 1):

Use the following jQuery:

```
$(".linkA").mouseover(function() {
    $("#boxA").fadeIn('fast');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $("#boxA").fadeOut('fast');
});​

$(".linkB").mouseover(function() {
    $("#boxB").fadeIn('fast');
}).mouseout(function () {
    $("#boxB").fadeOut('fast');
});​
```

See this [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/hKzAW/)

Comment: I think you don't need several hover for each link

Comment: nope, it's still like it was when I tried. Problem is that the box fades out when mouse enters it. I need the box to stay visible, until mouse leaves the link AND/OR the box like on this site on the very top links "compte" you can hover it and and small form shows up until mouse leave the link or the form : www.conforama.fr –

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".linkA").on('hover', function(e) {
    if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
      $("#boxA").fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
      $("#boxA").fadeOut('fast');
    }
});​
```

do with one hover, not need to write separate hover statement for each link.

#### If your link has only one class then its fine to use like below.

```
$(".linkA, .linkB").on('hover', function(e) {
    if(e.type == 'mouseenter') {
      $("#box" + this.className.replace('link','')).fadeIn('fast');
    } else {
      $("#box" + this.className.replace('link', '')).fadeOut('fast');
    }
});​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/9EJuR/2/)**

#### Note

You don't need `display: block`, because jQuery used this when it `.fadeIn()`.

Comment: nope, it's still like it was when I tried. Problem is that the box fades out when mouse enters it. I need the box to stay visible, until mouse leaves the link AND/OR the box like on this site on the very top links "compte" you can hover it and and small form shows up until mouse leave the link or the form : www.conforama.fr